# Change element inside ngFor with a ngClick

Tags: angular, typescript

> my english is not good, if the grammar is not right , please let me know.

I was trying to change text by clicking `<li>` in the ngFor element , but the click event doesn't work.

I have created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xCOmb9fZILlPThsX8eaB?p=preview) with a proper example.

You can also see the changes I have made checking the diff between my code and the angular.io Router Course [here](https://www.diffnow.com/?report=7xgzs)

For your information this were my steps:

- remove the async pipe in the ngFor
- change heroes variable to get() property in the component
- change onSelect method to modify `hero.name` Cumulative ＂Click＂ string to end

```js
@Component({
  template: `
    <h2 (click)="test1()">HEROES</h2>
    <ul class="items">
      <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes "
        [class.selected]="isSelected(hero)"
        (click)="onSelect(hero)">
        <span class="badge">{{ hero.id }}</span> {{ hero.name }}
      </li>
    </ul> 
  `
})
export class HeroListComponent implements OnInit {
  
 
  get heroes() {
    return [
       new Hero(11, 'Mr. Nice'),
       new Hero(12, 'Narco'),
       new Hero(13, 'Bombasto'),
       new Hero(14, 'Celeritas'),
       new Hero(15, 'Magneta'),
       new Hero(16, 'RubberMan')
    ]; 
  } 
  
  test1(){
    //alert(1);
  }  
  
  onSelect(hero: Hero) {
    hero.name += 'click';
  }

}
```

---

update 2016/12/14

When I found that getProperty would make ngFor repeated execution, I have created a plunker(plnkr.co/edit/bkXYuyLtq5OrPoEQpNmC?p=preview) with a little experiment

description of the schematic(imageshack.com/i/ponHcO7Vp)

- ngFor use get property () objects ,they get a maximum of 100 times because they always return new objects.
- When you re-enter the page through other Router, it will only be repeated maximum of 3 times, and all objects are re-generate (from the console.log you can see the call from the beginning of the accumulator recalculated)
- When you click on any of the elements of the page is triggered, will let NgFor re-set data, up to two

> This is not caused by get property, you can see from this link(jsfiddle.net/w31cqzdj/1/) through the for loop of native javascript and object.definedProperty will only call once
>
> output(imageshack.com/i/porsQYHAp)

Comment: and I was trying use Chrome Developer Tool Remove Elemnt and trigger another element click event , the deleted element is restored, why??

you can see gif by link (https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhVYy.gif)

Comment: You just deleted text that is why. You have to delete complete <li></li> element

Comment: I just demo ngFor will restored data after click event, if you delete complete <li></li>, it will be restored to the same result

Comment: aha! okay . I hope the posted solution is working for you

Comment: why I trigger click event then NgFor will be re-run when I use get property??

Comment: You don't have to formulate the rerunning . In Angular observables are registered , you have to provide the array , just like you did in the above code ,  if the array changes , your list will be updated accordingly . see this answere http://stackoverflow.com/a/41124408/3476801 . In this answer we are retaining the reference so that angular could check again , weather the array changed or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, but you are changing a new Hero reference, so that's why you don't see the changing effects. You need to pass the index so you have the reference for that object,instead of passing the hero object.

Here's a working version:

```
export class HeroListComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes= [];


  private selectedId: number;

  constructor(
    private service: HeroService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    //this.heroes = this.route.params
    //  .switchMap((params: Params) => {
    //    this.selectedId = +params['id'];
    //    return this.service.getHeroes();
    //  });
    this.loadHeroes();
  }

  loadHeroes() {

    this.heroes = [
       new Hero(11, 'Mr. Nicesss'),
       new Hero(12, 'Narco'),
       new Hero(13, 'Bombasto'),
       new Hero(14, 'Celeritas'),
       new Hero(15, 'Magneta'),
       new Hero(16, 'RubberMan')
    ]; 
  }

  test1(){
    alert(1);
  }

  isSelected(hero: Hero) { return hero.id === this.selectedId; }

  onSelect(index) {
    //this.router.navigate(['/hero', hero.id]);
    this.selectedId = this.heroes[index].id;
    this.heroes[index].name += 'click';
  }
}
```

And [here's](https://plnkr.co/edit/11rq5AtlP586KwsjvZAx?p=preview) a fork of your plunker with this version

Comment: why I trigger click event then NgFor will be re-run when I use get property??

Comment: Because the get property returns a new array every time.

Comment: What you mean is : get property() of typescript will be transform to `Object.defineProperty` of  javascript, so when it is accessed every time a new array is returned, and since the array is changed, NgFor will re-run once?

Comment: Yes, try putting a `console.log('Heroes')` inside your get property() and see how many times it's called.

Answer (score 0):

update your heroes variable as following :

```
 heroes: Array<Hero>= [
       new Hero(11, 'Mr. Nice'),
       new Hero(12, 'Narco'),
       new Hero(13, 'Bombasto'),
       new Hero(14, 'Celeritas'),
       new Hero(15, 'Magneta'),
       new Hero(16, 'RubberMan')
    ];
```

[this is the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ssRZu4PfgIuWknErtXeh?p=preview)

**ISSUE** : 
Issue was with the refrence of your typescript array , you were doing anonymous initialization and reference was not stored in any variable , I just changed the assignment to  heroes: `Array<Hero>= [..]`